# C++ - CRTP assign operator in parent not working

Tags: c++, crtp

I have this classes using CRTP (code is dummy, only for demonstartion of the problem):

```
template <class T>
struct IFoo 
{
    IFoo() {}
    IFoo(const char * x) {}

    //T & operator=(const char * x){ return *static_cast<T *>(this); } //not working

    void Test() { static_cast<T *>(this)->TestInternal(); }
};


struct Bar : public IFoo<Bar>
{
    using IFoo<Bar>::IFoo;

    Bar(const Bar & b) {}
    Bar(const Bar && b) {}

    //Bar & operator=(const char * x){ return *this;} //works

    void TestInternal(){}
};
```

And code:

```
Bar bar = "bar";
bar = "bar2"; //not working if assign operator is in IFoo
```

If I use assign operator in `Bar`, above code is working. However, with assign operator in `IFoo` it is not and I got error:

```
error C2280: 'Bar &Bar::operator =(const Bar &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
note: compiler has generated 'Bar::operator =' here
note: 'Bar &Bar::operator =(const Bar &)': function was implicitly deleted because 'Bar' has a user-defined move constructor
```

Why?

Comment: wrong `*` placement: `return *static_cast<T *>(this);`

Comment: @VTT Fixed, but th eproblem is still the same

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, did not thought about this. It works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is to `using` the base operator, just like you're currently `using` the base constructors:

```
using IFoo<Bar>::operator=;
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous response will make your code work.

But I would like comment out a couple of things in CRTP and static cast.
I will suggest the following:
Make constructors private on recurring pattern, to avoid bad use, particularly with castings.
Then you can access the constructor from derived as friend class, even if it is illegal you can create a wrapper.

```
template <typename T>
struct wrapper {
    typedef T type;
};

template <class T>
struct IFoo 
{
    typedef T temp;
    friend class wrapper<temp>::type;
private:
    IFoo() {}
    IFoo(const char * x) {}
    public:
    T & operator=(const char * x){ return *static_cast<T *>(this); } //not working

    void Test() { static_cast<T *>(this)->TestInternal(); }
};


struct Bar : public IFoo<Bar>
{
    //using IFoo<Bar>::IFoo;
    using IFoo<Bar>::operator=;

    Bar() {}
    Bar(const char *x) {}
    Bar(const Bar & b) {}
    Bar(const Bar && b) {}

    //Bar & operator=(const char * x){ return *this;} //works

    void TestInternal(){}
};

int main () {
     Bar bar = "bar";
     bar = "bar";
}
```